# Version checker. Has anyone else had this issue?

Tags: xml, versioning

In my work environment, we use a lot of open source. What we would like to do is automatically scan for apps that we use and get notified when they get updated. Seems like there should be a service somewhere that tracks versioning info and could notify us when a package changes. Something like an open source versioning XML feed maybe?
Anyone know of such a creature?
Nikki

Update:
Thanks to all: what I am after is a general XML/RSS feed that offers versioning info as a general information issue, definitely nothing that scans our boxes (super tight security) and definitely nothing windows related.

More info: we use a lot of open source packages on our slackware servers and having an XML/RSS feed that we could parse would allow us to write notification routines that alert us to version changes. I am assuming so far that no such creature exists.

Answer (score 2):

You can get RSS feeds from **[VersionTracker.com](http://www.versiontracker.com/windows/)**, keeping you informed about new releases.

If you're looking for software that monitors the version status of installed drivers and third party applications on your Windows systems and then shows you when new updates are available, have a look at **[VersionTracker Pro](http://download.cnet.com/VersionTracker-Pro/3000-2094_4-10223175.html)**.

[image]

VersionTracker Pro is shareware ($29.95), try before you buy.

Answer (score 1):

[Secunia](http://secunia.com/) has some nice applications that will scan your entire computer and compare your installed applications to their database and alert you when you have out of date apps.

- [Online Software Inspector](http://secunia.com/vulnerability_scanning/online/)
- [Personal Software Inspector](http://secunia.com/vulnerability_scanning/personal/)
- [Corporate Software Inspector](http://secunia.com/vulnerability_scanning/corporate/)

Comment: PSI is free, which is great!